# How to remove duplicate elements from one list and into another list in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

i have scenerio that i have three list

```
1) $scope.edit.user
```

each value in user list contains 'id','name','number' in the form of objects
 . Second list is

```
2) $scope.edit.duplicateUser
```

This list contains only ids ex: [12,13,14] in the form of array

if duplicateUser list contains some users which are present in user list then i want to splice that users objects from :

```
$scope.edit.user
```

and add into third list that is :

```
$scope.edit.intersectedUsers = []
```

Comment: Are the arrays, by chance, sorted by Id?

Comment: $scope.edit.user may contain few users with same ID? or single object per ID

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using lodash for your list/array/collection manipulation:

https://lodash.com/docs

Answer (score 0):

Using [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs):

```
$scope.edit.intersectedUsers = _.remove($scope.edit.user, 
    function(u) { return _.indexOf($scope.edit.duplicateUser, u.Id) > -1; });
```

If $scope.edit.duplicateUser is sorted, you can get a performance boost by adding `true` to `_.indexOf()` to do a binary search instead.

```
$scope.edit.intersectedUsers = _.remove($scope.edit.user, 
    function(u) { return _.indexOf($scope.edit.duplicateUser, u.Id, true) > -1; });
```

Comment: can we do the same with underscore.js?

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about collection manipulation on client side, you should use underscore\lodash.

```
    $scope.edit.intersectedUsers = _.find($scope.edit.user, function(user){
        if (_.contains($scope.edit.duplicateUser, user.id){
            return user;
        }
    }); //intersectedUsers will contain only the users with id from duplicateUser

    $scope.edit.user = _.difference([$scope.edit.user, $scope.edit.intersectedUsers); 
//User list will be modified to itself without the duplicated users
```

Installation instructions and more information about [underscore here](http://underscorejs.org/)

Installation instructions and more information about [lodash here](https://lodash.com/)